# Decoding %2F Laravel 5

Tags: php, json, laravel

i have this url that return a json format 
http://localhost/myproject/public/report/json/barcode/101-2016-10605030-001-1%2F2 but i get a

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 145
```

This is my Controller

```
public function barcode($val)
{

    return rawurldecode($val);
}
```

what i need to display :

```
101-2016-10605030-001-1/2
```

I already :
AllowEncodedStatus On

Though its working on a regular php code (Not in Laravel)

Comment: without the %2F its working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `%2F` to `%252F`:

```
public function barcode($val)
{
    return $val;
}
```

Comment: While this code may or may not resolve the issue, it would be helpful to explain _how_ or _why_ this code works and what is different than what the OP attempted.

Comment: the %2F is generated by using javascript encodeURIComponent() how can i change it to %252F?

Comment: Ok.. I found it.. In my javascript i did this encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(barcode)) on getJson url.. Thanks @rome 웃